Reprojecting Raster Tiles in BNG format on React Native Maps?
I am using template URL to display tiles from a third party API. That API for tile serves the tiles in 27700 format. React Native Maps Template URL expects it in 3857 or similar web mercator formats.
I am converting z/x/y slippy tile indexes to lat and long on my local server acting as an intermediary between react native maps and third party API. From that point I reproject the coordinates. However, I am stuck with it because react native map coordinates cover it globally and the coordinates the tiles coming from the server expect 27700 based BNG grid on same zoom levels.
So, for example react native maps would expect to cover the whole world at 0 zoom. Meanwhile the server only expects to cover UK on zoom 0 and has a different zoom to scale then on react native. I have tried Interpolation, reprojection, finding center of coordinates of the expected tile.
I am approaching it the wrong way. What would be correct approach, if in details?
